# ASP.NET MVC3: Publishing is excluding my CSS (.less) file

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, dotless

Originally I had my css .less file named `Site.less.css` so that intelligent type is active. Which worked fine.

I've recently needed to use the `@import "Site.less";`  ability. And unfortunately this doesn't work with `.css` on the end, because that would treat it as a CSS file, and not pass the .less parameters.

However, with the name `Site.less`, the publish (to IIS) feature is not including this file. I assume this is to do with an unrecognised file type? It is included in my solution explorer, and so should be copying it!

How do I get it to copy with publish? ( I can do it manually but shouldn't have to do this every time)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are the ".less" file properties set to "content"?

[image]

Comment: It is now ! Thanks. Yea, changing the file extension seems to set it to None. *scratches head*. I'll remember this in future. Thanks a lot. Dont suppose you know how do force publishing of an empty folder? I stuck in a blank txt file, but again, surely there is a better way?

Comment: @Doomsknight unfortunately a textfile/image etc. is the only way to do it